# Not getting images in imageButtons at all

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my layout file below, for the last linear layout, I added three image buttons with valid images and text. However they are not at all getting displayed in the app. Given below is the layout file for this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"

    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/female_default"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                    android:text="Balle"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                    android:text="Shaaba"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/mark_as_default"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Given is the snapshot of the image. As you can see, below the circular image all the three buttons are not visible at all.]

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  android:srcCompat="drawable/ic_menu_edit"
```

to

```
 app:srcCompat="drawable/ic_menu_edit"
```

srcCompat is an attribute of AppCompat library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use inbuilt Android resources. So you need to make following changes in your
ImageButton image source:

**//change this**

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_delete"/>
```

**//to this**

```
<ImageButton android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"/>
```

Make sure to change this syntax in all image button srcCompat attribute and it should work.

*If you have copy of those icons in your project drawables folder then **@drawable/ic_menu_delete** syntax will work*

Please let me know if it was of any help.

Comment: Use android:src instead of android:srcCompat and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the reason was that the 1st LinearLayout inside the parent LinearLayout has layout_height as "match_parent". Due to this, it was suppressing the LinearLayout containing the three ImageButtons. Changing that to wrap_content made it work fine.

```
android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```